# Select case with VB GUI (For School)

Tags: vb.net, select, case

Greetings and salutations. I really need help for school.

This is what I'm dealing with:

[image]

Cannot make selection until one option is picked.
The "You have selected a hostel location" text shouldn't show up until "Select Location" is pressed. 
My assignment is a hostel selection, allowing the user to select one or the other. Once the selection is made via btnselect, lblselected is supposed to show up, then the window is supposed to close. 
Please help me. I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm a web designer trying to expand my knowledge.

```
Option Explicit On

Public Class frmhostelselection

    Private Sub btnlondon_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlondon.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btndublin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndublin.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnselect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnselect.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnexit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexit.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub lblselected_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblselected.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub lblmsg_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblmsg.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: can you post some Code?

Comment: Yes sir! Sorry, don't hate me. Losing mind over here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i get you a logic

First on you `loadsub`

you must add

```
londonlistbox.enabled = false
dublinlistbox.enabled = false
```

then, add to you london button

```
dublinlistbox.enabled = false
london.enabled = false
```

and add the opposite to the dublin button

then, select location

```
select case londonlistbox and dublinlistbox
case londonlistbox.enabled = true
label1.text = londonlistbox.selecteditems
case dublinlistbox.enabled = true
label1.text = dublinlistbox.selecteditems
```

that's all

Comment: My assignment is a hostel selection, allowing the user to select one or the other. Once the selection is made via btnselect, lblselected is supposed to show up, then the window is supposed to close.

Comment: You haven't effort at all, so i won't provide full code to you

Comment: I've literally never done regular vb before, and never done a gui. I've only done vbscript. All I need is an idea of how I'd go about making that work, that is all.

Comment: I don't understand the loadsub part, explain please?

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the label. In visual studio, you want to select the label, and set its visible value to false. Or you can set it to be invisible for the formload event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
lblselected.visible = false

end sub
```

You then need it to show for the button click event.

```
lblselected.visible = true
```

From your picture i am unsure what the buttons are to do. You seem to have 2 actual locations to choose (as buttons) and another button which seems to act as a select button.

You also have requested a select case command in your question.

So perhaps you want t select case to load when you click the select location button, and that a value will be set if you click either of the other buttons?

As above said, you have made no attempt to try this yourself, so i won't write the code, but it sounds like you want this...

1. The 2nd label should be invisible until the select button is clicked.
2. You want to string or something that will identify what has been pressed. This string should be a global variable that is declared beneath the public path.
3. When either londen button or... other button is pressed, the global string should change to either London or...Dublin.
4. When you press the select button, it should load a select case method which will check for either london or dublin.

   ```
   Select case globalstring
   case "London"
   ' make label visible, maybe change lblselected text to reflect that London was pressed.
   case "Dublin"
   ' Make label visible, maybe change lblselected text to reflect that Dublin was pressed.
   case default
   ' Produce an error message saying that nothing was pressed.
   end Select
   ```

I'm guessing you also want images to show in those pictureboxs. Use initial image to get that one.

And the exit button will just be me.close()